# Duration between 2 dates based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table of data that shows different steps in a process, with a date/time each step was carried out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V61Y.png)

What I'm looking to do is add a column that calculates the time in minutes between each step, however it has to relate to the claimID, so in the image shown I would be looking for difference between each step for the top 4 results (as they share the same claimID), then the following 6 results, etc.

Can anyone help? I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Can you please post the expected output for the example data you posted?

Comment: Hi please accept my apologies - the initial image I posted didn't have the statussetdate column in order. What I'm looking to achieve is to populate a column with the duration (in minutes) between each step in the process based on ClaimID - so for rows 1-4, the results I'd expect to return would be 0 in row 1 (as this is the first step), 80 mins in row 2, and 2 minutes in rows 3 and 4. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join the table to itself using the Row_number to get the previous date and do a DateDiff on the 2 values..

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimID ORDER BY StatusSetDate) Rn
    FROM ClaimStatus
)
SELECT  curr.*, 
        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(minute, prev.StatusSetDate, curr.StatusSetDate),0)
FROM    cte curr
        LEFT JOIN cte prev ON curr.ClaimID = prev.ClaimID AND curr.Rn = prev.Rn + 1
ORDER BY curr.ClaimID, curr.StatusSetDate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this JamieD77 - works brilliantly! I was just wondering how  to add this to an Insert statement so I have a column that is populated with this? I've only been learning SQL for a few weeks so really appreciate the help :)

Comment: cte's will also work with Insert statements like so `;With cte As (Select data ) Insert into dbo.table select * from cte`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of SQL Server you are using you can either use a self join or the `lag` window function (this should work in SQL Server 2012+):

```
select 
    claimid
    , statusid
    , statussetdate
    , coalesce(datediff(minute, 
               lag(statussetdate) over (partition by claimid order by statussetdate), 
               statussetdate
              ),0) as diff_in_minutes
from 
    your_table
order by 
    ClaimID
    , StatusSetDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm using SQL Server 2008 :)