# How to calculate days between status on datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with steps history for a request.

Here is an example of the data:

[image]

I need to place on days how many days between each status has been passed.

Of course if there is only one status then the days should be the days elapsed between the transaction day and today's date.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you want to do it in C# or SQL?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34138229/718373) looks to be catering for something similar in SQL, please have a look.

Comment: in C#, SQL would be also very nice

Comment: why not just a `for` loop and handling the case for the `out of index of array`

Comment: Can you please show what the results should be for your sample data?

Comment: Sigh.  Its `PAID`, not `PAYED`, unless your status relates to something you are doing on a ship.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to solve the issue:
Iterate through the collection, subtract the date column value of the previous row from current row `.TotalDays()` will returns you a double value indicates the day difference. this can be implemented as follows:

```
var temTable = myDatatable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < temTable.Count; i++)
{
    double days = 0;
    if (i != 0)
        days = ((DateTime)temTable[i]["date"] - (DateTime)temTable[i - 1]["date"]).TotalDays;
    temTable[i]["days"] = days;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.dDate,r.dHour,r.dStatus,DATEDIFF(
DAY,LAG(r.dDate,1,GETDATE()) 
OVER (ORDER BY r.dDate),r.dDate) AS DAYS 
FROM tbData r;
```

I believe, above query in Sql Server will provide the desired output.
But to update the table with a new column "days" some additional/other code is required. I'm still working on it. And if you get the solution please post... 
I didn't take time into my consideration...... You add that too....
You can use a field with type datetime (replace date and hour), will reduce the risk....

Comment: SELECT dDate,dHour,dStatus,DATEDIFF(
DAY,LAG(dDate,1,GETDATE()) 
OVER (ORDER BY dDate),dDate) AS DAYS FROM tbData; =>gives similar result

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH newTable AS (
SELECT dStatus,ABS(DATEDIFF(
DAY,LAG(dDate,1,GETDATE()) 
OVER (ORDER BY dDate),dDate)) AS dDays FROM tbData
)
UPDATE tbData SET dDays=nt.dDays
FROM newTable nt
WHERE nt.dStatus = tbData.dStatus;
```

I believe this will resolve your problem.....
Hour field is not considered.....Thank You....